# Errors in the Youtube API v3 python examples

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Because Youtube Engineers monitor stack overflow with tags related to Youtube API v3

When executing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser
```

I am receiving the following error:

from apiclient.discovery import build
ImportError: No module named apiclient.discovery

Please Google Engineers correct the samples so people starting with the API don't get stuck with this kind of errors.

Comment: Have you tried reporting it as a bug?  https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)

Comment: I used StackOverflow as suggested in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support as it´s an error of the documentation not the API. It seems that google enginyeers are monitoring the questions here that have certain tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error disappears changing with this minor changes:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser
```

All this applies to Python 2.7.X